# Docker not run in debian wheezy

Tags: java, javascript, android, python, ios

i installed Docker in debian wheezy 64bit and when i try to run it these error are displayed:

/usr/local/bin/docker: line 1: --2015-03-17: command not found
/usr/local/bin/docker: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/local/bin/docker: line 2:`Resolving get.docker.io (get.docker.io)...162.242.195.84'

how to solve this problem?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as the very first line of the script that you're executing.